# jQuery to update actual CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First off: I'm aware of the jQuery.css() function, but it doesn't work in my case.  I'll explain why.

I have a jQuery color picker being used to change the highlighting of a website.  I want to apply that color picker to the border of an element which **only shows on hover**.

The jQuery.css() function only applies the CSS to elements it finds, and does not work on the `:hover` CSS attribute.

I've tried adding a CSS class which I toggle on the hover, but it comes back to the same problem: I'm trying to change ONLY the hover value.

There's got to be a way to do this, but I've been searching StackOverflow and Google for the better part of an hour now, so I'm invoking [xkcd #627](http://xkcd.com/627/)

Comment: Have you tried using the hover event? http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Yes, but where do I apply it?  If I put the code in the updateColor(color) function (which gets called when you change the color picker) then it applies the color even once you stopped hovering.

Comment: If my answer doesn't explain everything, please provide your code for the color picker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event to achieve the same results.

```
$('selector').hover( function(){
    //A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.
    $(this).css('property','value');
}, function(){
    //A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.
    $(this).css('property','value');
});
```

Comment: handlerIn/handlerOut gave me a Javascript error, but you gave me the idea to use .mouseover and .mouseleave instead, which works!  Thank you!

Comment: @Bing I removed handlerIn/handlerOut which fixes the error.  $( selector ).hover is identical to $( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut ); so its preference which one you use.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the great info (and quick response)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an alternative answer.

If you need to dynamically change your CSS then there is something wrong with your CSS. It's very strange that you need a definition, that you can't toggle with a class and has to be generated dynamically.

---

Let's say you have a widget that can be in two modes: inactive or active. When it's active elements in it should respond visually to a hover event, when it's not, they shouldn't.

```
<div id="my-widget" class="my-widget-container">
    <div class="element">Something to look at</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.my-widget-container .element { background-color: #ffffff; }
.my-widget-container.active .element:hover { background-color: #00ff00; }
```

You switch the mode by:

```
$("#my-widget").addClass("active");
```

This will activate the `:hover` line for the element which now appears interactive.

If I knew more about your situation I could perhaps fix a fitting solution.

---

Also, `jQuery.css` is poorly named, perhaps `jQuery.style` would be a better name since that is exactly what it does.

Comment: The problem with this is that the `background-color` on the `:hover` needed to dynamically changed via the Javascript color picker.  There's still a good chance I did something wrong, but that's why I didn't see adding a new CSS class as the answer.  (Here is my color picker, by the way: http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/)