# JQuery .is :checked returns false every time

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

Ok, I've been fiddling with this for almost 40 minutes now... WTF am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/aMhjJ/

```
 <input type="Checkbox" name="E1019" id="E1019" value="1">
 <div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#E1019').change(function () {

    if ($('E1019').is(':checked')) {
            $('#result').html('checked');
        } else {
            $('#result').html('unchecked');
        }
});
```

Problem solved: Missing # in if statement: $('E1019') should be $('#E1019')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have used [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector) instead of [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector) - missing `#` in front of `E109`

```
if ($('#E1019').is(':checked')) {
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Tnp6/)

---

But you can also use the `checked` property of the dom element

```
$('#E1019').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#result').html('checked');
    } else {
        $('#result').html('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7WEpt/)

Comment: +1. What is your daily reputation max? 200? after that you can give as chnace to earn some reputation. And can you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985465/javascript-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-dynamically-on-fly-creating-style)

Comment: @Phoenix I'll give a try... probably in the evening

Comment: OMG - I knew it was something staring me right in the face, needed another set of eyes. Thanks

Comment: @Phoenix sure... let me know once you are done editing the question

Comment: Ok. I will post here or somewhere else in your questions as comment